# How to put array items in ascending order

Tags: c#

I'm trying to put this array in ascending order but I don't know why when I'm running it I'm getting what I want.

```
private static void sort()
{
    int[] array = new int[3];
    int order = array[0];
    Console.WriteLine("plz enter 3 numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Array.Sort(array);
        Console.WriteLine("the number in order  ", array [i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```

Comment: FYI, your getting downvotes, likely because this is a commonly asked question with many existing answers already. You're expected to research questions yourself before posting

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `Array.Reverse(array);`

```
private static void sort()
        {
            int[] array = new int[3];
            int order = array[0];
            Console.WriteLine("plz enter 3 numbers");
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                Array.Sort(array);
                Array.Reverse(array);
                Console.WriteLine("the number in order  ", array[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: but it does not put them in order and it does not print them

Answer (score 0):

you need to first read the numbers , then sort and last but not least print them

```
private static void sort()
{
    int[] array = new int[3];
    int order = array[0];
    Console.WriteLine("plz enter 3 numbers");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    Array.Sort(array);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("the number in order  ", array [i]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
```